# Can we define $f$ in $0$ so that $f$ is continuous in $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

$$f(x)=\frac1{\arctan{(|x|^3)}}, \quad x \neq 0$$

Also, if answer is yes, is that expansion to class $C^1(\mathbb{R})$.

What i have is this:

$$\lim_{x\to 0-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0-}\frac1{\arctan{(-x^3)}}=\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac1{\arctan{(-x^3)}}=?$$

$?$ would be $f(0)$, but i can't find this limit, can't use L'Hospital because it's not undetermined form.

Comment: This is trivial as stated. Should the problem really be $f(x) = \arctan (1/|x|^3)?$

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite discontinuity at x = 0. When you take the limit of the arctangent function of -x^3 around 0, the limit is 0. Thus the limit of the reciprocal is +/- infinity.You can't define f(x) in terms of a piecewise function that both exist at x =0 and the limits converge to the same number.